# How to load static files with spring boot inside a docker container hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, static-files

I got my SpringBoot app running in a docker container built from a Dockerfile and hosted on AWS ubuntu instance.
Everything is working perfectly, except I have an image, a css file and a js file that does not load. Upon inspecting the page, these files show 404 not found error.
I have used winscp to upload my files to my aws instance. In myApp folder is where my docker file is and where I build my container.

Directory Structure is:

```
myApp
  -Dockerfile
  -target
     -myApp.jar
  -src
     -main
        -java
            -[all my code in respective subdirectories]
        -resources
            -static
               -my.js
               -my.css
               -my.jpg
            -templates
               -folder1
                    -html
                    -html2
               -folder2
                    -html
                    -html2
```

I am almost certain my problem lies in the docker container and my dockerfile.

Spring Boot automatically looks for static files in /src/main/resources/static. I'm thinking my docker container does not have this file structure.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-14-jdk

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/myApp

ADD . /src/main/resources/static

ADD target/myapp.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myApp.jar"]
```

When i build the container it shows everything copied and built successfully, but the files are not being reached. And what is weird to me is spring boot is serving the correct templates from the static folder. I am at a complete loss on this one. I have tried adding the resources individually from the dockerfile and still no luck.

Comment: I think you are mixing different things. 

On a jar file you can easily put the resources you need and access them from your application (as you said in src/main/resources). 

No docker modifications needed. From where do you need to access those files?

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all. I'm teaching myself, and the course on spring boot very briefly went over containerization and not very well. Covered enough of the bare minimum basics for me to research what I needed to know. I thought that was the whole purpose of a jar file myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting `WORKDIR` and then copying `.jar` into that location using relative path but when you are copying the other stuff (`/src/main/resources/static`), you are using absolute path which is completely destroying your folder structure (since those files are not copied into folder referenced by your `WORKDIR`). You have probably forgot `.`(dot) in front of that path - `./src/main/resources/static`.

Run `docker exec -it <image-id> bash` to get access into your running container and see what was copied where if you are not sure, fixing the stuff in your Dockerfile should be easy from then on.

Comment: That was exactly what I was doing wrong. a missing "." Thank you can't believe I over looked that.